# When to throw Exception

Tags: c#, oop, exception

Although I read a lot about Exception Handling, I am still not sure when to throw one and when not.

For example I have an API as three tier architecture and in the DB layer events can occur.

- Try to **receive** a customer from database, but customer with the given id was not found.
- Try to **delete** a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.
- Try to **update** a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.

In the first case I am not throwing an exception, because nothing really "goes wrong". My repository function just returns "null" to tell upper layers that nothing was found.
But the other two cases are already tricky.

It does not make sense to me if a deleteById-function returns "null" if the id was not found. I could return "false" if the deletion was not successful and "true" if it was successful. But then I have to transport this from database layer, through domain layer to the presentation layer. Throwing an Exception would just be easy to me. 
But in this case I also did not produce "unexpected behaviour". Like in the first case, nothing "goest wrong". Isnt there any kind of "best pracice"?

What would you do?

Comment: Well, the real problem here is why do you ask to delete or update a customer that doesn't exist in the database?

Comment: Usually, all my deletes return an int that indicates the number of items that where delted. Same goes for update. You may have updates that update multiple items. Update by ID is just a special update. Can still return the same thing. I tend to not differenciate and think too much into it. It´s up to personal taste though.

Comment: So you would pass the information how many items where updated, deleted through the business logic to the upperest tier and not throw an exception... yes thats what I am droing right now, but with "true", "false"...

Comment: I would throw an exception when **delete** or **update** gets an invalid Id. I think this is the easiest way to avoid any problems that can occur. When you called these two logic you have to catch the error and send a message to the user about what did or did not he/she do. Never let the errors reach the user its an security vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I argue that you shouldn't throw an exception in any of these cases - here's why:
Exceptions should be used for exceptional things - mainly things you can't control in code - such as a network connection error and stuff like that.
Throwing exceptions for non-exceptional situations is just, well, vexing, as Eric Lipprt [explains so much better than I can.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

- > Try to **receive** a customer from database, but customer with the given id was not found.

Well, that's a no brainer - You didn't find a customer in the database - return null. No reason to throw an exception because there's nothing exceptional in this situation.

- > Try to **delete** a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.

If the customer was found in the database, then this operation would result with the removal of this customer.
If it wasn't found in the database - the end result is still the same as if it was found - so why should you care it wasn't there in the first place? Again, no reason to throw an exception.

- > Try to **update** a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.

This one is the most tricky to explain, but there are basically two legitimate ways to handle this situation:

One way is to do what any database does when an update statement has a where clause that doesn't fit any row in the table - and that's simply do nothing.
As far as letting the client know if there was an actual update or it was a no-op, you can check the number of rows effected and return true/false or customer/null to the client.

The other way, is to convert the update to an "upserts" - so if the customer is not found on the database, simply create a new customer.
This can also be indicated back to the client using a simple true/false return value. In that case, you should name the method properly - `AddOrUpdateCustomer`, for instance.

Comment: Thats similar to what Max replied. It absolutely makes sense to me!

Comment: I basically agree, but there are situations where I would throw nevertheless: If I now that the records must exist (I loaded them myself beforehand and do something now) I would throw, since this is then really unexpected.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon I wouldn't throw an exception even in this case. A where clause that returns nothing is a common event, not an exceptional one - there are better ways to indicate to the client that something didn't go as expected, and exceptions should not be used as flow control.

Comment: @ZoharPeled But you would throw an Exception if an Element already exists on an insert-operation? For example the customer with the serial number 7236 already exists and someone tries to insert a customer with this id. In this case an AlreadyExists exeption would be right?

Comment: @DavidMason if the serial number is supposed to be unique, then yes, that's probably a good place to use an exception, both because this is a somewhat exceptional situation, but more importantly, when you throw an exception, the calling method can't ignore it (well, at least one of the methods in the calling stack have to catch it) but it's easy for the calling method to ignore whatever your method is returning - and in this case, that's the more important reason, IMHO, to throw an exception instead of returning a value indicating success/failure.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use *exceptions* as a way to signal caller for expected execution flows. This should be done returning a meaningful value as the function returns. If your function return is more complex and couldn't be expressed by simple `true`/`false` returns, you can declare an `enum` to use as return value or even a `Tuple` in more complex scenarios.

> Try to receive a customer from database, but customer with the given id was not found.
>
> Try to delete a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.
>
> Try to update a customer by id, but the id was not found in database.

All this 3 possible situations should be well handled by DB and when such a path happens, just return a value to the caller with enough information so it can handle the result and act properly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to throw an exception when something unexpected goes wrong. with your example =>

1. a getById call return item | null if not found => there is no error if does not exist
2. the repo.Delete function MUST have a valid id => db function throw an exception(better if ArgumentException )... BUT the controller/manager need to catch(ArgumentException) and then 2 options:

   2a. 'delete not exist item' => success -> after method call, item
   does not exist

   2b. es: controller send error message to client 'Item you're want to delete does not exist'
3. repo.Update function must have valid id => like above without 2a option

if function NEED this param => throw

if function manage 'not found=null' case => not throw

Comment: ArgumentExceptions are for invalid arguments. Incase of a delete action, the end result of a success (customer found and deleted) and of customer not found is the same - why bother with an exception? as the end client of the software, why should I care if the item was deleted or wasn't there to begin with?

Comment: delete function => if item was deleted(success), but if the item was not found , there is an error in the code, for example if i wrote something wrong and i pass 0 as id , without an error message i took a false positive test (for example)

Comment: If the item doesn't exist in the first place it doesn't have to be a problem in the code. Here's a quick demonstration: Suppose you have a website with a data grid. Two customers view the same records on different computers. One of them deletes an item from the database, and a minute later the other one, unaware that the item was already deleted, tries to delete the same item. Should the second user get an error message?

Comment: ok , not an error message but some message 
=> i provide a list of user to the admin, admin can delete a user (only one admin)
if admin pass me an id that is not in the user list i provide to the admin => error

there is a different kind of situations, every one need custom 
behavior

Comment: "throw ex and catch it" OR "return null/false and check the result of a func"...

there is a small difference between this 2 behavior i think 

,for the getById and delete func for example

Comment: I still think at least 99 times out of a 100, seeing an error message like  "couldn't delete the customer because there wasn't one in the first place" is kinda silly, Though I do agree that in some rare situations it might be needed - but it's still not a good reason to throw an exception - where a simple return value can get the job done in half the price.